# SQL function in arel select without activerecord instantiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I want to get a SQL result as hash from an `::ActiveRecord_Relation`, because instantiating actual ActiveRecord objects is very slow. Normally I use `pluck` then zip the result into a hash:

```
keys = [:name, :created_at]
hash = relation.pluck(*keys).map{|row| Hash[*keys.zip(row).flatten]}
```

But the query I need has SQL function, like:

```
SELECT name, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) - 3600 as hour_before_created FROM ...
```

I can do this using Arel's `select`:

```
rel = rel.select("name", "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) - 3600 as hour_before_created)")
hash = rel.as_json(except: :id)
```

Which gives the correct output, but unfortunately instantiates ActiveRecord objects.

What is the correct way to get a hash with the appropriate headers from each `as` clause, without instantiating ActiveRecord objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this; it's not pretty but it works.
The simplest way to do something like this would be to make and ActiveRecord relation but instead of querying the db, call to_sql on it. Then do:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

(That's off the top of my head; corrections welcome)

That returns an array which you can zip with Model.column_names or an array of whatever columns you actually selected.

Not sure how to to_sql on Arel, but I imagine it's possible.

Comment: I think you mean zip with res.fields, where res is the Mysql2::Result from `execute`:

   `sql = rel.select("name", "UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_at) - 3600 as hour_before_created)"); 
   res = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql); 
   hash = res.to_a.map{|row| Hash[*res.fields.zip(row).flatten]}`

That's working for me.